# CCTV Camera as a Broadcast Camera

Tags: video, camera, broadcasting

I am trying to make a camera multicam live broadcast setup (at FHD), have 2 cameras already, but would like a third. I am trying to be sub-$60, and found a [varifocal and zoom camera.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016XJ5WPO) It has a RCA output via BNC (and I have plenty of BNC). If I get that, I would need a RCA to HDMI to fit my setup, but now the question is: **Is getting a CCTV camera as a "broadcast camera" worth it?**

Obviously the quality is not going to be as good as a proper camera, but would it suffice?

I'm open also to recommendations on SUPER cheap cameras

Thanks All!

Micah

Comment: What are you connecting to? What other cameras do you have? Also, RCA isn't a signal type, it is just a connector that is typically only used for consumer grade analog signals.

Comment: In my setup, I am going to be using the Blackmagic Atem Mini Pro, which has 4 HDMI inputs (no SDI). Right now I'm just in the planning phase, but I already have a Canon t3i with a clean feed out, and a old, but usable, JVC GZ-HD300BU. Then as the question states, I'm also looking for another camera. 

In your opinion, what would be the cheapest reliable way to transfer HDMI over long distances (50-100ft). I was thinking about using composite video to transfer because it has a 100-200 ft limit vs. the 50ft limit of HDMI.

Comment: Composite analog video will not only give you a massive drop in quality, but will also only give you a 4x3 raster. You could do anamorphic, but the quality will degrade even further. You haven't said what your budget is, but there are some <$100 HDMI over UTP extenders on the market.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. My budget for this all is sub-1000 total or as cheap as I can make it. The switcher is 600 USD already, so I'm pretty limited. I am a high-school student and work at its auditorium. One more thing before I stop bugging you: thoughts on HDMI over cat 5? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I got my start with Broadcast Engineering in High School, so good for you! I'd spend the little bit extra on Cat6/6A. It looks like most of the extenders rate their distances based on that. Cat5 might make it the same distance or it might not. You can probably squeeze a little more distance out of the extenders with bonded and/or shielded cable, but that will significantly drive up cost. (However, if money was no object, I'd choose to go over Fiber instead of UTP). Feel free to move this conversation to chat if you want to continue the discussion.